# How to change CHARACTER_SET_NAME and COLLATION_NAME for a certain column?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, utf8mb4

I have a column with `utf8` `CHARACTER_SET_NAME` and `COLLATION_NAME` `utf8_general_ci`. I need to change the column to use `utf8mb4` and `utf8mb_unicode_ci` respectively.

I am using mysql 5.6

Answer (score 0):

[ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY [COLUMN] col_name column_definition](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html)